# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'driver' referenced before assignment in python 3.10

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

new to python could someone help on this

```
import pytest
from selenium import webdriver


@pytest.fixture()

def setup(browser):
    if browser == "chrome":
        driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        print("Launching chrome browser.........")
    elif browser == "firefox":
        driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        print("Launching firefox browser.........")
    return driver

def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--browser")

@pytest.fixture()

def browser(request):  
    return request.config.getoption("--browser")
```

Comment: You have no default value, so if `broswer` is something other than "chrome" or "firefox", you'll return a variable that has not been set.  You can either set a default value in the `addoption` call, or use an `else:` clause in your setup.

Comment: Thanks man its works used else:    could you help how to use with  default value in the addoption call @TimRoberts

Comment: Really, 30 seconds with Google would have answered this.  `parse.addoption("--browser", default="chrome")`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to supply a default:

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--browser", default="chrome")
```

Alternatively:

```
def setup(browser):
    if browser == "firefox":
        driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        print("Launching firefox browser.........")
    else:
        driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        print("Launching chrome browser.........")
    return driver
```